# On-premises data gateway - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, onpremises-gateway

I have an On-premises data gateway installed on my server to connect to my SQL server. For my Power apps it is working great. How can I use this gateway to retrieve data in Power BI? I can't select it "get data". How do I do this?

Kind regards,

Sander V.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway is meant to connect your on-prem data to the power bi service cloud. To get data from your sql server, you would use the Get Data > SQL connector.

Comment: But why is this way used at power apps? Via SQL connector I don't get connected.

Comment: do you have access to the SQL Server? You must enter the proper address and credentials after you get data. The SQL connector is one of the most popular methods of reading data in power bi.

Comment: Yeah we have this. But you need to be in the range of the wifi or LAN. To get connected so it is not possible to refresh this or get realtime data. U know what I mean?